# Why doesn't std::string automatically append (or crash) when the index is out of range?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++, I have some C experience and I was excited to see std::string as a replacement to char[]. In my learning process I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
std::string constToLowercase(const std::string &s){
    std::string newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        newString[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    return(newString);
}
```

the goal being to accept a string and return a lowercase version without affecting the original string. 
What I found was that this function always returned an empty string. I imagine it's because I'm indexing into memory that the string hasn't reserved, but I would have expected an exception or for the program to crash, not simply return nothing.

My next thought was to try this (change on line 2):

```
std::string constToLowercase(const std::string &s){
    std::string newString = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        newString[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    return(newString);
}
```

which was successful, and obviously a good solution to my problem.

I'm perturbed by my lack of understanding though, and while trying to figure out why my original function didn't work, I tried this (change on line 2 reverted, change on line 4):

```
std::string constToLowercase(const std::string &s){
    std::string newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        newString = newString + static_cast<char>(tolower(s[i]));
    }
    return(newString);
}
```

this function worked as I expected function 1 to work. My question really is why doesn't function 1 act like function 3? As a followup why doesn't function 1 crash?

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It doesn't append because that is not what operator[] is defined to do, in either C or C++. It doesn't crash, in your case, because what you are seeing is undefined behaviour, just like in C.

Comment: If you are asking why `operator[]` was not defined to have this convenient behavior, consider that implementing it can't be done with zero overhead and that most use cases for `operator[]` would not benefit from it.

Comment: If you want to pay the cost of bounds checking then use [`std::string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

Comment: `std::string::operator[]` doesn't crash outright for invalid indices for the same reason that `std::vector::operator[]` doesn't: making it validate all the time is costly, and you are trusted to know what you're doing.  If you want validation, then use `std::string::at`.

Comment: In debug mode, with good implementations, it would crash. std::map has the insert-if-missing behavior you want, but that's not an optimal compromise for every structure.

Comment: *"I would have expected an exception or for the program to crash, not simply return nothing."* - At a guess I would assume that you are using a `std::string` class that implements the short string optimization, meaning, that every `std::string` object allocates a small static buffer for short strings. In that case, you are writing into allocated memory, and the program does not (immediately) crash. It's just that the length is not updated, resulting in a still empty string.

Answer (score 4):

C++ attempts to give you raw C level performance with higher level types.

It leaves some things as undefined behavior, and doesn't check bounds, because that would slow it down.

Often there are APIs that are safer, like `.at` which throws when out of bounds.

There is something else -- what should it pad with?  (A space?  A null?)  And how should it deal with accessing element `2^60`?  These are hard questions to answer perfectly.

You can easily write your own function that does exactly what you want.  It isn't hard.  However, if they had baked that into `std::string`, you would never be able to get the "raw metal" performance out.

Comment: "*And how should it deal with accessing element `2^60`?*" - that was my first thought too when I read the question title. Nobody would want a string to auto-grow so much to accommodate that index.

Answer (score 3):

> My question really is why doesn't function 1 act like function 3?

Because [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) for `std::basic_string::operator[]` says so:

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. **If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined**.

> As a followup why doesn't function 1 crash?

Because **Undefined Behaviour does not mean crash**. It may crash, it may not. What it would not do for sure - always work properly.